# Ошибка во время преобразования данных с БД

Tags: java, jdbc

При данном коде: `Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id"))`!

Я получаю ошибку **Invalid value for getInt() - 'id'**

Не понятно в чём проблема, я же могу в принципе преобразовать с `valueOf(int)` к `String`, а после в Long ?

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    if (Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id"))) == ((Customer) instance).getId()) {
        System.out.println("The "+resultSet.getString("id")+" is already in use !");
        if ((resultSet.getString("cust_name").equals(((Customer) instance).getCustName()))) {
            System.out.println("The "+resultSet.getString("cust_name")+" is already in use !");
            existence_checker++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в поле `id` текущей записи у Вас содержится значение `id` – не число, а строка, поэтому это не целочисленное (и вообще не числовое) значение не может быть получено методом `getInt(...)`.

Comment: Можете дать пример получения числа с Result set ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, Так Вы и пытаетесь получить число. Ошибка в том, что в результате запроса (как минимум в одной) записи в поле `id` находится **НЕ** число. Посмотрите саму таблицу.